# What needs to be done to reuse newspapers for insulation?

Tags: home, reuse, insulation

I seen a couple of shows that were pointing newspaper as a very good insulator, that attracted my interest so I was wondering if any of you have any input on this?

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to do it yourself:

Shred them.

**Fireproof them.**

Insulate.

It is extremely important to treat newsprint with fire-retardants before using them as insulation. Without treatment, newsprint stuffed into wall cavities or attics is a serious fire hazard.

A better option is to simply **purchase cellulose insulation**. It's made from recycled newspapers and is treated for proper fire resistance by the manufacturer. In my opinion, it's safer and more sustainable to confine the chemical treatments to a factory rather than your personal garage, yard, or workshop.